# My table is too wide to fit in one page, could anyone help me out?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
q\_s_ {a,b} \stackrel{.}{=} (q(s_ {semantic}), \  q(s_ {QoS}))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q\_s_ {a,b} \stackrel{.}{=} (q(s_ {mt}), \  q(s_ {dst}), \  q(s_t),\  q(s_c),\  q(s_r),\  q(s_a))
\end{equation}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Quality Aggregation Matrix for semanic web service composition}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$Composition$\\
$Construct$\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{$Quality Factors$}    
\\ \cline{2-7} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$Functional$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$Non Functional$} \\ \cline{2-7} 
$& $Q(s_ {mt})$ & $Q(s_ {dst})$ & $Q(s_t)$ & $Q(s_c)$ &  $Q(s_r)$   & $Q(s_a)$   \\ \hline
$Sequence$ $&  $\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_ {mt})$ & $(\sum_{n=1}^m q(s_ {dst}))/m$&$\sum_{n=1}^m q(s_ {t})$&$\sum_{n=1}^m q(s_ {c})$&$\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_r)$&$\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_a)$\\ \hline
$Parallel$ &  $\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_ {mt})$ &$(\sum_{n=1}^m q(s_ {dst}))/m$ & $max(q(s_ {t}))    &$\sum_{n=1}^m q(s_ {c})$ &$\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_r)$  &$\prod_{n=1}^{m} q(s_a)$ \\ \hline
$Choice$ & $\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s \cdot q(s_ {mt})$ & $\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s \cdot q(s_ {dst})$  & $\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s \cdot q(s_ {t})$ & $\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s \cdot q(s_ {c})$ &$\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s \cdot q(s_ {r})$ & $\sum_{n=1}^m w\_s   \cdot q(s_ {a})$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\small` or `\tiny` after the definition of table environment.

Comment: thank you. it works, any size between small and tiny , coz tiny is a little bit too small

Comment: You may use `\footnotesize` also.

Comment: thank you so so much, problem solved. millions of thanks

Comment: @JeffreyWong if it solved your problem, it is better to accept this answer to help reduce the number of unnecessarily unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
 ... your tabular ...
}
```

then you can choose the default fontsize. Needs package `graphicx`.